# PageParameters cause onConfigure of Page to be called multiple times

Tags: java, url, wicket

The project where I'm trying to implement the usage of a BookmarkablePageLink works with one BasePage and then fills it with different Panels.
The URL (e.g. www.example.com/?number=12345 ) goes to the BasePage retrieve some information from the database and passes that along to a newly constructed panel.
If I debug the code and go through it once, everything is showing correctly. However, the `onConfigure` method of the BasePage keeps getting called.
So far I haven't been able to figure out why

```
protected void onConfigure() {
    ToekenningSearchCriteria criteria = new ToekenningSearchCriteria();
    criteria.getSearchItem().setNumber(pageParameters.get("number").toString());
    Toekenning toekenning = getToekenningService().findWithCriteria(criteria); 
 this.setContentPanel(this.getContentPanelFactory().getContentPanel("SOME_CONTENT_PANEL_TYPE", toekenning));
}
```

I expect the `onConfigure` method to only be called once but it's called infinite times.

Edit: placing the code in the onBeforeRender method gives the same result.

Comment: The onConfigure javadoc explicitly states: *NOTE: Component hierarchy should not be modified inside this method* - But that seems to be exactly what you are doing unless the method setContentPanel is named rather badly.

Comment: After reading your comment, I've replaced the code in the onBeforeRender method but still the same result. I've edited the original question to match this.

Comment: It is kind of hard without seeing the actual code what those methods do. Maybe you might have some kind of infinite recursion in their somewhere: eG the ContentPanelFactory might create a Panel that then creates another panel with the Factory again etc. pp

Answer (score 1):

You need `onInitialize()` instead of onConfigure() .

onInitialize is like the constructor. The difference is that in Component#onInitialize you can access the parent via getParent() and the markup via getMarkup(). Since we are talking about Page here there is no parent.

onConfigure() is being called for every request for stateful pages. You can do `if (!hasBeenRendered() {...} )` to make sure the body is executed just once.